# Sending message to ActiveMQ embedded broker hangs

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I want to mock out my activemq instance in my unit tests. So I set up the queue as so:

```
    camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    camelContext.setErrorHandlerBuilder(new LoggingErrorHandlerBuilder());
    camelContext.getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT_SECONDS);

    routePolicy = new RoutePolicy();
    routePolicy.setCamelContext(camelContext);

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL("vm:localhost");
    // use a pooled connection factory between the module and the queue
    pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    // how many connections should there be in the session pool?
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(this.maxConnections);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(this.maxActiveSessionPerConnection);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setCreateConnectionOnStartup(true);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setBlockIfSessionPoolIsFull(false);

    JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration(pooledConnectionFactory);
    jmsConfiguration.setDeliveryPersistent(false);

    ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("vm:localhost");
```

However, when I send a message to the queue like this:

```
producerTemplate.sendBody(uri, message);
```

the process hangs at

```
FailoverTransport.oneway:600
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong using the embedded broker? This all works fine when connecting to a tcp endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URL to `vm://localhost` (or even `vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false` which is common in unit tests to avoid temp data on disk).

Comment: Still hangs, in the same place.